# I need help making a menu bar in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to implement a menu bar in my program for a few days now and i cant seem to get one running. I would like someone to look at my code and give me a template to follow to making a menu bar.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, databaseFilePath, userFilePath):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.moviesFilePath = moviesFilePath
        self.currentUserFilePath = currentUserFilePath
        self.createWindow()

    def changeFilePath(self):
        self.currentUserFilePath = functions_classes.changeFP()
        functions_classes.storeFP(self.currentUserFilePath, 1)

    def createWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Movies')
        #Menu Bar
        fileMenuBar = QMenuBar().addMenu('File')
```

The method changeFilePath is what I would like to be called when a menu option called 'Change user database location' is called from the menu bar File. I have read that actions are the key to this but when every i have tried to implement them they haven't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QMainWindow` class already has a [menu-bar](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar).

So you just need to [add a menu](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmenubar.html#addMenu-2) to it, and then [add an action](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction) to that menu, like this:

```
    def createUI(self):
        ...
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        action = menu.addAction('Change File Path')
        action.triggered.connect(self.changeFilePath)
```

**EDIT**:

Here's a full, working example based on your example class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, databaseFilePath, userFilePath):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.databaseFilePath = databaseFilePath
        self.userFilePath = userFilePath
        self.createUI()

    def changeFilePath(self):
        print('changeFilePath')
        # self.userFilePath = functions_classes.changeFilePath()
        # functions_classes.storeFilePath(self.userFilePath, 1)

    def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Equipment Manager 0.3')
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        action = menu.addAction('Change File Path')
        action.triggered.connect(self.changeFilePath)   

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow('some/path', 'some/other/path')
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: For both of the methods provided, when the code is run the python shell looks like it tries to build and raise the window but then it restarts.

Comment: @user1921942. I don't really understand your comment, but I've added a working example to show how to run the code.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong the first time round but following your edit I got it working thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The logic to add a Menubar with usable items is something like this

```
def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Equipment Manager 0.3')
        #Menu Bar
        fileMenuBar = QMenuBar(self)
        menuFile = QMenu(fileMenuBar)
        actionChangePath = QAction(tr("Change Path"), self)
        fileMenuBar.addMenu(menuFile)
        menuFile.addAction(actionChangePath)
```

Then you just need to connect the action `actionChangePath` to the signal `triggered()` with something like

```
connect(actionChangePath,SIGNAL("triggered()"), changeFilePath)
```

Probably there are some better solution (but why did you not use the Designer ?), but this one should be work

Comment: For both of the methods provided, when the code is run the python shell looks like it tries to build and raise the window but then it restarts.

Comment: The reason I didn't use the designer is because i don't know how to convert the file to a GUI program.

Comment: The file is converted using `pyuic`, which generate a .py file that can be imported into your main script