# Simple PyQt5 tutorial does not show menu bar

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.7

The window appears but the menu bar shows only "Python3.7", which is what
it shows if I don't create a menu bar. This is taken almost verbatim from the tutorial [here](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-menu/). MacOS High Sierra.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction    

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Menu Bar'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Edit')
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('View')
        searchMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Search')
        toolsMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Tools')
        helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')
        self.show()   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is a screen shot of the Mac menu bar and the top left portion of the window:
[image]

**Update:** I found this question: [I need help making a menu bar in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334518/i-need-help-making-a-menu-bar-in-pyqt5?rq=1) about the same problem. I ran the code that worked for the OP and it worked! I'll try to find the difference between that code and mine and post again.

Comment: What I remember is that the menubar in Mac OS does not appear in the upper part of the window but in the upper part of the screen. See https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/429-4296744_whats-in-the-menu-bar-mac-os-sierra.png

Comment: Right, that is what I would expect. I just added a partial screen dump to show what I get.

Comment: How are you launching the application?

Comment: I get the same result whether I launch from the command line or from the Run menu in PyCharm.

Comment: For me I had to use      
    mainmenu = self.menuBar();        
    mainmenu.setNativeMenuBar(False)

Answer (score 0):

**It's a MacOS thing.** I haven't researched this issue in depth, but two things seem clear: empty menus will not display and menu items with names beginning with
"About", "Exit", "Quit", will be placed under the program menu.

Play with this under OS X:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 menu bar test'
        self.initUI()

    def print_change(self):
        print('change')

    def print_byebye(self):
        print('bye bye')

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        filemenu = menubar.addMenu('File')

        """ Play with these options in Mac OS X:

            confuse_me = False, False

            You see a File menu with two actions "Change" and "Bye Bye" respectively 
            printing "change" and "bye bye". The program menu contains "Services...", 
            "Hide ...", "Hide Others", and "Quit ..." which exits the program.

            confuse_me = True, False

            The File menu contains only "Bye Bye". The "About" item appears in the program 
            menu and prints "change". The "Quit" item still quits. 

            confuse_me = False, True

            The File menu containd only "Change". There is no "About" in the program menu,
            and the "Quit" item prints "bye bye"

            confuse_me = True, True

            The program menu has "About" and "Quit" respectively printing "change" and "bye 
            bye". These is no File menu.
        """

        confuse_me = False, False

        text = "About a Boy" if confuse_me[0] else "Change"
        pathaction = filemenu.addAction(text)
        pathaction.triggered.connect(self.print_change)

        text = "Quitting is not an Option" if confuse_me[1] else "Bye Bye"
        exitaction = filemenu.addAction(text)
        exitaction.triggered.connect(self.print_byebye)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```